# True/false: If $N\unlhd G$, then for any homomorphism $f:G\to G/N$, the kernel of $f$ contains $N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I want to know whether the following statement is true. And if it is, how one can prove it.

"If $N\trianglelefteq G$, then for any homomorphism $f:G\to G/N$, the kernel of $f$ contains $N$."

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Note: quotients are defined in terms of cosets, and to remind us of this, we use the notation $G/N$, not $\frac{G}{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true in general.

For example take $$G := \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} \ \text{ and } \ N:= \langle (1,0,0,....) \rangle $$
Then $\varphi: G \to G/N, (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \overline{(0,a_1,a_2,...)}$ is an isomorphism, i.e. $\ker \varphi = 0 \nsupseteq N$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.